# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen zurzeit und jetzig?

Tags: synonym

In anderen Forums, kann ich nur was uber zurzeit und derzeit finden

Comment: *Jetzig* ist ein Adjektiv, *zurzeit* ein Adverb, es gibt also einen fundamentalen Unterschied bei der Wortart. Kannst Du die Frage präzisieren?

Comment: achso ich wusste das nicht. ich war nicht dafür spezifisch suchen

Answer (score 2):

"jetzig" ist ein Adjektiv, das aus "jetzt" gebildet wurde, ähnlich wie auch "vorherig" aus "vorher" entsteht.

> Der *jetzige* Präsident ist jünger als der *vorherige*.

Die Nachsilbe "-ig" ist (ebenso wie die etwas aus der Mode gekommene Nachsilbe "-en") für diesen Zweck (nämlich aus Worten anderer Wortart Adjektiva zu formen) gebräuchlich:

> Samt, samt*ig* (auch: samt*en*)
> Teig, teig*ig*
> rollen, roll*ig* (bei Katzen, im Östrus)
> laufen, läuf*ig* (bei Hunden, im Östrus)

"zurzeit" (ebenso wie "derzeit", etc.) ist ein *Adverb*. Zum Unterschied von einem *Adjektiv* bestimmt es nicht Eigenschaften eines Nomens näher, sondern Eigenschaften eines Verbs.

> *Derzeit* (jetzt) *sind* alle Leitungen besetzt ...

Das "derzeit" bezieht sich auf das "sein", das Prädikat des Satzes und ein Verb. Hingegen:

> Der *jetzige Zustand* der Leitungen ist, daß alle besetzt sind.

Das "jetzig" bezieht sich auf den "Zustand", ein Nomen.

Insofern, als Adverbien und Adjektiva überhaupt die gleiche Bedeutung haben können, ist die Bedeutung der beiden Worte tatsächlich gleich: sie schreiben ihren jeweiligen Adressaten analoge Eigenschaften zu.